# Getting array value inside nested object React Redux

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have an object with an array inside it. Object is returned from MongoDB.

```
  {
    brand: "OPEL",
    createdAt: "2022-12-17T17:44:31.693Z",
    image: [
        {
        public_id: 41658465461,
        url: http://www.cloudinary.com,
        },
    ],
    licensePlate: "DR126",
    mileage: 526,
    model: "corsa",
    qrCode: "#21566",
    updatedAt: "2022-12-17T17:44:31.693Z",
    _id: "639dffff33060ff5c3c796eb",
  }
```

The problem is whenever I try to get the image url in my React component `obj.image[0].url` it returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`
`console.log(obj.image[0].url)` returns `undefined`

After refreshing page returns 2 logs:

1. `console.log(obj.image[0].url)` returns `undefined`
2. `console.log(obj.image[0].url)` returns `"http://www.cloudinary.com"` (actual link)

I assume that object is not ready before I am trying to access it.

I looked over everyone and couldn't understand where is the issue and how can I solve it.
Thank you in advance for taking a look at this !

Tried forEach() loop, found 1 solution at stackoverflow didn't do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 0):

change `obj.image[0].url` to `obj?.image[0]?.url`

the `?` checks if the field exists and is not `undefined` then access to it

Comment: I tried using `?` but sometimes it returns component and sometimes, it throws an error. 
The moment I posted it, I realized that my `payload` from redux takes time to load. So it was React fault. I took advantage of redux `pending` conditionally rendered the component. Now it's working like a charm.